# Rmarkdown printing overlapping plot and individual plots

Tags: r, histogram

I'm able to print out the overlapping histogram of two series I'm looking at, but for some reason, Rmarkdown is printing out both the overlapping histogram plot (in colors below) and the individual histograms of each series (one shown below).

Is there a way I can only include the colored, overlapping histogram in Rmarkdown instead of all three plots? Thanks.

**Code:**

```
install.packages('Lahman')
library(Lahman); library(tidyverse)

pitch19 = Lahman::Pitching %>%
  filter(yearID == 2019, BFP >= 500) %>%
  mutate(lgID = factor(lgID))

p1 <- hist(pitch19$BAOpp[pitch19$lgID == 'NL'])
p2 <- hist(pitch19$BAOpp[pitch19$lgID == 'AL'])

plot( p1, col=rgb(0,0,1,2/4), xlim=c(0.15,0.35),
      main='Opposition Batting Average (BAOpp) by League',
      xlab='BAOpp', plot=FALSE)
lines(density(pitch19$BAOpp[pitch19$lgID == 'NL']), col=rgb(0,0,1), lwd=3)
plot( p2, col=rgb(1,0,0,2/4), add=T, plot=FALSE)
lines(density(pitch19$BAOpp[pitch19$lgID == 'AL']), col=rgb(1,0,0), lwd=3)
legend('topleft',legend=c('National Lg.', 'American Lg.'),
       fill = c(rgb(0,0,1), rgb(1,0,0)), bty = 'n',
       border = NA)
box()
```

**Rmarkdown output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so L for me. I was assigning `hist(p1)` back to `p1` which, because `plot=FALSE` was not one of the arguments in `hist(p1)`, was plotting `p1`. (Same goes for `p2`.)

All I did was remove that functionality from happening while assigning `p1` and `p2`, updated the current `plot=FALSE` to `plot=TRUE` (or, removing them since TRUE is default), and then running the code.

**Code:**

```
p1 <- pitch19$BAOpp[pitch19$lgID == 'NL']
p2 <- pitch19$BAOpp[pitch19$lgID == 'AL']

hist( p1, col=rgb(0,0,1,2/4), xlim=c(0.15,0.35),
      main='Opposition Batting Average (BAOpp) by League',
      xlab='BAOpp')
lines(density(pitch19$BAOpp[pitch19$lgID == 'NL']), col=rgb(0,0,1), lwd=3)
hist( p2, col=rgb(1,0,0,2/4), add=TRUE)
lines(density(pitch19$BAOpp[pitch19$lgID == 'AL']), col=rgb(1,0,0), lwd=3)
legend('topleft',legend=c('National Lg.', 'American Lg.'),
       fill = c(rgb(0,0,1), rgb(1,0,0)), bty = 'n',
       border = NA)
box()
```

**Output:**

Same as colored histogram from above